# how to move files from one directory to another depending on some validations in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

Spring integration polls for the files in a directory , does some validation on it and then i want to move it to another directory. How to achieve the same?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFileIntegration(@Value("${inbound.file.poller.fixed.delay}") long period,
                                              @Value("${inbound.file.poller.max.messages.per.poll}") int maxMessagesPerPoll,
                                              TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                                              MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource
                                             ) {



    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(fileReadingMessageSource,
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
                            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)))
                            .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
            .filter(validateDeal, "validate", e -> e.discardFlow(sf -> sf.handle(fileImproperEmailwriter,"sendEmail")))

            .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FileReadingMessageSource` populates these headers to the message:

```
return getMessageBuilderFactory()
                .withPayload(file)
                .setHeader(FileHeaders.RELATIVE_PATH,
                        file.getAbsolutePath()
                                .replaceFirst(Matcher.quoteReplacement(
                                        this.directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator), ""))
                .setHeader(FileHeaders.FILENAME, file.getName())
                .setHeader(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, file);
```

So, you always have access to the original file. To move it to different path you can use `java.nio.file.Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)` utility. And really use it somewhere in the flow.

Unfortunately, the flow you demonstrate doesn't have any clues how are you going to move file at all. On the other hand it isn't clear why you can't perform that on the `ApplicationConfiguration.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL` subscriber side for files passed validation and some other move in the `discardFlow()`. You always can use `PublishSubscribeChannel` to have several subscribers to perform some parallel work for the same message.

**UPDATE**

```
@Bean(name = ApplicationConfiguration.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
MessageChannel myOutboundChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}
```

And since you use already `.channel(ApplicationConfiguration.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)` this bean is going to be used instead. I guess you have some subscriber or `IntegrationFlow` to consume this channel. What you want to do should be expressed as one more subscriber or an appropriate `IntegrationFlow` for post-process work.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the below:-I want to  perform that on the ApplicationConfiguration.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL subscriber side for files passed validation and some other move in the discardFlow(). Can you please direct me to some examples how  PublishSubscribeChannel works?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Any example of PublishSubscribeChannel()?

Comment: See Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel.There has to be a bean and you can have several consumers on it - two `IntegrationFlow` beans with the `.from(ApplicationConfiguration.OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)` should be enough for you. You can find some code in the `samples` project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/dsl/cafe-dsl/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/dsl/cafe/lambda/Application.java